# UsageStats always the same when i start the method every x seconds

Tags: java, android, android-service

#### Im trying to make a service that would provide data of usagestat every x second. However i always getting the same value after x second. I already clear the map to include new data set from usagemanager. below is my service class thank you in advance.

---

I do know that in order to retrieve queries every x time, we may use queryevent. However, the total time in foreground for this fit my project, and i already tested using the code for adapter. In the adapter, it do retrieve usage time, however it only provide new value on restarting the activity where the adapter used.

```
public class PushService extends Service {

    private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
    private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_Id_1";
    private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID2 = "Channel_Id_2";
    private static final int _DISPLAY_ORDER_USAGE_TIME = 0;
    private static final int _DISPLAY_ORDER_LAST_TIME_USED = 1;
    private static final int _DISPLAY_ORDER_APP_NAME = 2;
    private static final boolean localLOGV = false;
    private int mDisplayOrder = _DISPLAY_ORDER_USAGE_TIME;
    private AppNameComparator mAppLabelComparator;
    private LastTimeUsedComparator mLastTimeUsedComparator;
    private UsageTimeComparator mUsageTimeComparator;
    private PackageManager mPm;
    private UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager;
    public HashMap<String, Long> mapToFirebase = new HashMap<>();;
    public ArrayList<UsageStats> mPackageStats;
    public ArrayMap<String, String> mAppLabelMap;
    public List<UsageStats> stats;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

        /*notice*/
        startForeground();

        if (intent != null){
            String uid = intent.getStringExtra("parentUID");
            if (!uid.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(this, uid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Handler ha=new Handler();
                ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //call function
                        pushAppList();
                        mapToFirebase.clear();
                        loadDataToMapForFirebase();
                        Log.d("mapservice", mapToFirebase.toString());
                        ha.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                    }
                }, 10000);



            }

        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    public static class AppNameComparator implements Comparator<UsageStats> {
        private Map<String, String> mAppLabelList;

        AppNameComparator(Map<String, String> appList) {
            mAppLabelList = appList;
        }

        @Override
        public final int compare(UsageStats a, UsageStats b) {
            String alabel = mAppLabelList.get(a.getPackageName());
            String blabel = mAppLabelList.get(b.getPackageName());
            return alabel.compareTo(blabel);
        }
    }

    public void pushAppList(){
        mAppLabelMap = new ArrayMap<>();
        mPackageStats = new ArrayList<>();
        mPm = getPackageManager();
        mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -5);
        mLastTimeUsedComparator = new LastTimeUsedComparator();
        mUsageTimeComparator = new UsageTimeComparator();

        stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, cal.getTimeInMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());

        if (stats == null) {
            return;
        }

        ArrayMap<String, UsageStats> map = new ArrayMap<>();

        int statCount = stats.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < statCount; i++) {
            Log.d("", String.valueOf(stats.get(i).getTotalTimeInForeground()));
            android.app.usage.UsageStats pkgStats = stats.get(i);

            // load application labels for each application
            try {
                ApplicationInfo appInfo = mPm.getApplicationInfo(pkgStats.getPackageName(), 0);
                String label = appInfo.loadLabel(mPm).toString();
                mAppLabelMap.put(pkgStats.getPackageName(), label);

                UsageStats existingStats =
                        map.get(pkgStats.getPackageName());
                if (existingStats == null) {
                    map.put(pkgStats.getPackageName(), pkgStats);

                } else {
                    existingStats.add(pkgStats);
                }

            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                // This package may be gone.
            }
        }
        mPackageStats.addAll(map.values());

        // Sort list
        mAppLabelComparator = new AppNameComparator(mAppLabelMap);
        sortList();
    }

    public static class LastTimeUsedComparator implements Comparator<UsageStats> {
        @Override
        public final int compare(UsageStats a, UsageStats b) {
            // return by descending order
            return (int)(b.getLastTimeUsed() - a.getLastTimeUsed());
        }
    }

    public static class UsageTimeComparator implements Comparator<UsageStats> {
        @Override
        public final int compare(UsageStats a, UsageStats b) {
            return (int)(b.getTotalTimeInForeground() - a.getTotalTimeInForeground());
        }
    }

    private void sortList() {
        if (mDisplayOrder == _DISPLAY_ORDER_USAGE_TIME) {
            if (localLOGV) Log.i(TAG, "Sorting by usage time");
            Collections.sort(mPackageStats, mUsageTimeComparator);
        } else if (mDisplayOrder == _DISPLAY_ORDER_LAST_TIME_USED) {
            if (localLOGV) Log.i(TAG, "Sorting by last time used");
            Collections.sort(mPackageStats, mLastTimeUsedComparator);
        } else if (mDisplayOrder == _DISPLAY_ORDER_APP_NAME) {
            if (localLOGV) Log.i(TAG, "Sorting by application name");
            Collections.sort(mPackageStats, mAppLabelComparator);
        }
    }
    public void loadDataToMapForFirebase(){
        /*TODO UPDATE DATA ONBACKGROUND*/
        String system_sign = "android";
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();


        if (mPackageStats.size() != 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < mPackageStats.size(); i++){
                if (pm.checkSignatures(system_sign, mPackageStats.get(i).getPackageName()) == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH) {
                    Log.d("CheckAppSys", mPackageStats.get(i).getPackageName() + " is sys.");
                } else {
                    String usagetime = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(mPackageStats.get(i).getTotalTimeInForeground() / 1000);
                    Pattern special= Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                    Matcher matcher = special.matcher(Objects.requireNonNull(mAppLabelMap.get(mPackageStats.get(i).getPackageName())));

                    boolean constainsSymbols = matcher.find();

                    if(!constainsSymbols){
                        mapToFirebase.put(mAppLabelMap.get(mPackageStats.get(i).getPackageName()), mPackageStats.get(i).getTotalTimeInForeground());
                    }

                    Log.d("maptofirebase", mapToFirebase.toString());
                    Log.d("CheckApp", mPackageStats.get(i).getPackageName() + " is not sys.");

                }
            }

        }
    }
    private void startForeground() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, UsageStatsActivity.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                    NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Channel 1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel1.setDescription("This is channel 1");

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(
                    NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID2,
                    "Channel 2",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );
            channel2.setDescription("This is channel 2");

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
                NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) // don't forget create a notification channel first
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Monitoring apps.")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question but why did you choose Java?

Comment: It written in Java ?